# Передача данных между двумя горутинами

Tags: многопоточность, golang

Задача написать калькулятор, где одна функция - читает из консоли три символа, другая - считает и выводит в консоль ответ. Без разделения на ввод/вычисление всё работает, а при попытке подружить 2 горутины, всё валится из рук.

```
func main() {

    myChan := make(chan interface{}, 4)

    input := func() {
        var a int
        var b int
        var symbol string
        fmt.Scan(&a)
        fmt.Scan(&b)
        fmt.Scan(&symbol)
        if symbol == "S" {
            myChan <- false
            myChan <- a
            myChan <- b
            myChan <- symbol
        } else {
            myChan <- true
            myChan <- a
            myChan <- b
            myChan <- symbol
        }
    }

    calculate := func() {
        a := (<-myChan).(int)
        b := (<-myChan).(int)
        symbol := (<-myChan).(string)
        if symbol == "-" {
            fmt.Print(" = ", a-b, " ")
        } else if symbol == "+" {
            fmt.Print(" = ", a+b, " ")
        } else if symbol == "*" {
            fmt.Print(" = ", a*b, " ")
        } else if symbol == "/" {
            fmt.Print(" = ", a/b, " ")
        } else {
            panic("Wrong input!")
        }
    }

    go input()
    for (<-myChan).(bool) {
        go calculate()
        go input()
    }
}
```

Идея такова: в канал заливается `bool` который символизирует то, нужно ли вызывать функцию `calculate`, `x S y` -  форма для выхода из программы. Первый символ из канала читается в `for`, три остальных - в функции `calculate`, но что бы я не делал, валится с ошибкой.

EDIT: Без горутин тоже не работает, при вводе `1 + 1` в канале почему-то лежит `true 1 0 "1"`

Answer (score 0):

```
    go input() // 0
    for (<-myChan).(bool) { // 1 // 2 // 3 // 6
        go calculate() // 4
        go input() // 5
    }
```

0. Запустили конкурентную задачу, которая пишет в myChan и сразу перешли к 1
1. Ждём ввода юзера
2. Юзер закончил ввод и послал `true 1 1 +`
3. Читаем из myChan `true`, в канале осталось `1 1 +`
4. запустили параллельную задачу, которая **будет** читать из myChan и сразу перешли к 5
5. запустили параллельную задачу, которая **будет** писать в myChan и сразу перешли к 6
6. читаем из myChan, там лежит `1 1 +`, потому что ни (4) ни (5) ещё не успели сработать